# Cloning content type edit link

Tags: routes

When developing a site I often want to be able to access content type definition from the level of a viewed node representing it. So basically I'd say I'd need a new MENU_LOCAL_TAB with the path `/admin/structure/types/manage/%`.

What hook should be used so to not replace/override the already existing path? I would not like the corresponding item to disappear from Admin Menu. I just want to have a handy duplicate shortcut tab within a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get a tab with exactly that path in it, as it won't match the `node/%` path and the tab simply won't show.

The easiest way I can think of to do it would be to create a proxy page that does match that pattern. Something like:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/manage-ct'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage content type',
    'access arguments' => array('something appropriate to your install'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_node_manage_proxy',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_node_manage_proxy($node) {
  $type = str_replace('_', '-', $node->type);
  drupal_goto('admin/structure/types/manage/' . $type);
}
```

That way the tab will appear, but as soon as the user clicks through to the page it will redirect to the node type form.